# morphism corresponding to number of sections of a bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider $F$ to be a vector bundle on a  Projective variety $V$. We know that $F$ has a section is same as saying that there exists an injective map $\mathcal O_V \to F$.

Now assume that we are in a specific case, where $V \subset \mathbb P^3$ is a smooth surface.  If $F$ is a rank $2$ bundle on $V$ having at least $h^0(\mathcal O_V(m)), m \in \mathbb N$ many sections, then can we conclude along the same line as that of the previous paragraph that there exists an injective map from $\mathcal O_V(m) \to F$?

In other words, in this context, is it easy to see that the map $\mathcal O_V \to F$ extends to $\mathcal O_V(m) \to F$? (or is there a more down to earth explaination to this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true. For instance, take $V=\Bbb P^1\times\Bbb P^1$ and $F=\mathcal{O}(0,n)^{\oplus2}$. Then the existence of an injective map $\mathcal{O}(m)\to F$ for $m>0$ implies the existence of an injective map $\mathcal{O}\to \mathcal{O}(-m,n-m)^{\oplus2}$. But the latter sheaf has no global sections.

Comment: thanks!. Actually my intention was to understand the situation when $F$ is a rank $2$ slope stable bundle (w.r.t a hyperplane section $H$ of $V$). Can we say anything in that situation?

Comment: I don't usually work in that area, so I'm not sure (perhaps you should ask a new question). In the future, it would be helpful if you added motivation like that to your question so you can avoid a "actually I wanted xyz" in the comments later.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I would ask a separate question.